# Linux. Not printing to file

Tags: c++, linux, runtime-error

i'm just coding module for HLDS server extension metamod. I wrote a simple utility function for writing logs in format %LOGNAME%_%DATE%.log
In windows that function is working fine, but in linux it create file but write nothing.
First I try to search information about that, but I do not found a solution. I try to fflush file handle, set buffer to _IONBF mode, but nothing is helping. Thank you very much for reading this and helping me with that problem.

```
void UTIL_LogToFile(char* szFileName, const char *fmt, ...)
{
va_list     argptr;
va_start ( argptr, fmt );
vsnprintf ( g_szLogString, sizeof(g_szLogString), fmt, argptr );
va_end   ( argptr );

char* szFilePath = new char[strlen(GlobalVariables::g_szDLLDirPath) + 12 + 30 + 1];
char* szLogFile = get_timestring("_%Y%m%d.log");
sprintf(szFilePath, "%slogs/%s%s", (GlobalVariables::g_szDLLDirPath), szFileName, szLogFile);
FILE* hFile = fopen(szFilePath, "a+");
delete[] szFilePath;
delete[] szLogFile;
if(hFile == NULL)
{
    char szError[256];
    sprintf(szError, "Error fopen: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    SERVER_PRINT(szError);
    clearerr(hFile);
    return;
}

fprintf(hFile, g_szLogString);
if(ferror(hFile))
{
    char szError[256];
    sprintf(szError, "Error fprintf: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    SERVER_PRINT(szError);
    clearerr(hFile);
    return;
}
fclose(hFile);

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why don't you use `vfprintf` to print directly to the file, instead of using a temporary (and global) buffer? And for `szFilePath` and `szLogFile` why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: How do you know what error it gives? I don't see any error checking code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I will refactor that code after fixing problem with EAGAIN, i just didn't know about `vfprintf`. 
I do not use `std::string` because all of modules staff is writed on "C"

Comment: @Galik I delete that code, it was just printing `strerror(errno)` to console

Comment: after which line? The `fopen` or the `fprintf`?

Comment: @Galik after `fopen`

Comment: You should really post the code that produces the error because how do we know you didn't have a bug in the way you reported the error?

Comment: Are you checking if `hFile` is `NULL`?

Comment: It may help you to isolate the problem if you check the return code of each statement and only print `errno` if it indicates an error.

Comment: Also, when you do that, post the full error messages returned by `std::strerror(errno)`.

Comment: @Galik I do that. It looks like a didn't catch error correctly. Know it no error, just not add to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only check `errno` ***if and only if*** the previous function failed.

If the previous call didn't fail the value of `errno` is *undefined*.

So to properly check for errors you must ***first*** check if the `fopen` call returned a null pointer:

```
FILE* hFile = fopen(szFilePath, "a+");
if (hFile == nullptr)
{
    perror(szFilePath);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error was in other functions:
Changed source code: https://github.com/In-line/metamod_unprecacher/commit/08b2fabd03f838bee62913b0d2a4f4a4bbf1e6df